# How to send PUT request properly to webAPI application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/WordsAPI/"+wordData.ID,
        data: { word: wordData}
    });
```

Part of my C# code:

```
// PUT: api/WordsAPI/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutWord(int id, Word word)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != word.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        [...]
    }
```

In VisualStudio debugger I can see that app executes second BadRequest. All data in variable "word" on server side is null. I have no idea why. "id" variable is OK, it stores proper ID.

In javascript debugger in Firefox everything seems to be ok. wordData isn't null (wordData.id is sent properly to server) and I can see that all data was succesfully sent to server.

What could be wrong? What should I do?

**EDIT:**

Request in firefox (this is what is sent by browser):
[image]

Comment: should work.. try to change `data: { word: wordData}` to `data: JSON.stringify(wordData)` and make sure your `wordData` has the same properties as `Word word`

Comment: You can also mark you `word` with `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: I'm not sure if "wordData has the same properties as Word word". I mean: in Word class I have one property that contains DateTime value. In my app I send my Word variable to client, client modifies this data and send it back to server. I suspect that "DateTime" property is actually "string" on server side. What should I do then?

Comment: @simoco nothing will change, it will be still string as it is now

Comment: What is the definition of `Word`?

Comment: @async http://pastebin.com/SAMT5xgS

Comment: `In javascript debugger in Firefox everything seems to be ok.` - show your request body

Comment: @simoco OK, I've pasted it into my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server-side code works fine for me. 
However, the JavaScript should be as follows.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/WordsAPI/"+wordData.ID,
        data: wordData
});
```

I'm assuming `wordData` is an `Object` with a sample definition

```
var wordData = {
    ID: 5,
    UsersLanguage: "string data"
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vsevolod You need to add the `[FromBody]` tag in front of the Word class of the API method for sure. Secondly as Simoco says you need to make sure that the wordData you are sending has the same structure as your Word model.

meaning if you class looked like this

```
public class Word{
int id {get; set;}
string someText {get; set;}
}
```

Then your Word you are sending from the javascript needs to have the same structure

```
var word = {id : 1, someText: "text string"};
```

I would also suggest that you debug in VS on the method to make sure its being called. You can see what is being picked up if you hover over the Word parameter

Comment: 1. I've added [FromBody] still doesn't work. 2. Don't ModelState.IsValid check that? If yes, it seems like model is ok...